# syntax to put a column values into a single variable in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table STUDENT with a column NAMES.that column contains 10 rows ,

in SQL when i write

```
SELECT @variable= NAMES FROM STUDENT ;
```

it wiil display all 10 rows data in a single row ;

How to achive this in MySql?
please help me

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(variable SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM student
GROUP BY 1
```